# How to code Menues / Sub Menues in .Net Core Windows Forms Application in Visual Studio 2019 C#

Tags: c#, windows, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

I am using Visual Studio 2019 and making Windows Application in .Net Core 5.0 but I stuck on a point i.e. how to code Menus and Sub Menus (Drop Downs), because .Net Core does not provide the ease of access like .Net 4 (On development time on mouse over one can see the Sub Menus and Dbl+Click on it). Kindly give me the proper way to code Menus / Sub Menus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to do it manually.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        // Added Menustrip (id 'menuStrip1') with one item (fileToolStripMenuItem1) from UI and 
        InitializeComponent();
        ConstructMenu();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
    }       

    private void ConstructMenu()
    {
        // Define new toolstrip item
        ToolStripMenuItem openFileToolStripMenuItem1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
        openFileToolStripMenuItem1.Name = "OpenfileToolStripMenuItem1";
        openFileToolStripMenuItem1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(37, 20);
        openFileToolStripMenuItem1.Text = "&Open File";
        
        // event
        openFileToolStripMenuItem1.Click += OpenFileToolStripMenuItem1_Click;

        // Add it to parent toolstrip item
        fileToolStripMenuItem1.DropDownItems.Add(openFileToolStripMenuItem1);
    }

    private void OpenFileToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // ImplementedException;
    }
}
```

[image]